# Cвернуть лист объектов с подсчетом поторений используя stream()

Tags: java, java-stream, java-8

В поисках элегантного решения задался вопросом: Как преобразовать список **объектов** в массив с подсчетом количества повторений. Т.е если на входе есть

```
class Example {
    private String s;
    public Example(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // для иллюстрации 
        if (obj instanceof Example) {
            return this.s.equals(((Example) obj).s);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

List<Example> list = Arrays.asList(new Example("example1"), new Example("example2"), new Example("example1"), new Example("example3"));
```

Требуется получить Map содержащий:

```
          Key                       Value
-------------------------------------------
obj equals new Example("example1")   2
obj equals new Example("example2")   1
obj equals new Example("example3")   1
```

Интересует решение именно для абстрактного класса где экземпляры будут сравниваться основываясь на результате `equal()` и используя stream API. Для частного случая со строками или при группировке по полю проблем нет.

Для свертки по строковому полю можно поступить вот так:

```
Map<String, Long> messagesMap =
     this.list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getS(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере ничего не мешает вам группировать не по полю, а по объекту, то есть вот так:

```
Map<Example, Long> messagesMap =
       list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

Не работает это потому, что используемый `Collector` в качестве `accumulator` использует `HashMap`, который сравнивает объекты сперва по `hashCode`, а не по `equals`.
Я думаю, вам следует реализовать методы `hashCode` для использования `HashMap` и `compareTo` для использования `SortedMap`.

Пример с реализованным `hashCode`:

```
@Test
public void ttt(){
    List<Example> list = Arrays.asList(new Example("example1"), new Example("example2"), new Example("example1"), new Example("example3"));
    Map<Example, Long> messagesMap = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
    messagesMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue()));
}


class Example {
    private String s;
    public Example(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public String getS(){
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // для иллюстрации
        if (obj instanceof Example) {
            return this.s.equals(((Example) obj).s);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return s.hashCode();
    }
}
```

> $Example@737d1c09 : 1
>
> $Example@737d1c08 : 1
>
> $Example@737d1c07 : 2

Comment: Точно, ключевые слова здесь hashMap и hashCode. Спасибо.